# printing latex axes values using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

```
objects = ('AB_{3}', 'AB_{5}', 'AB_{10}', 'AB_{55}', 'AB_{1}', 'AB_{200}')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
```

I want to print y_pos as a latex formula. Is there a way I can set the format of a tick values in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib uses [mathtext](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) to typeset latex-like markup. All you need to do is using the math mode in your labels.

```
objects = ('$AB_{3}$', '$AB_{5}$', '$AB_{10}$', '$AB_{55}$', '$AB_{1}$', '$AB_{200}$')
```